# Iframe responsive with tailwind

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm trying to fit an iframe inside a div using tailwind, but I cannot figure out how to make the iframe responsive.

What kind of class do I need to use to make for example the following to work?

```html
<div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-50 py-6 flex flex-col justify-center relative overflow-hidden sm:py-12">
  <img src="/img/beams.jpg" alt="" class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 max-w-none" width="1308" />
  <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-[url(/img/grid.svg)] bg-center [mask-image:linear-gradient(180deg,white,rgba(255,255,255,0))]"></div>
  <div class="relative px-6 pt-10 pb-8 bg-white shadow-xl ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 sm:max-w-lg sm:mx-auto sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
    <iframe src="https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/zsnkxfmw?embed" width="800" height="600" allowfullscreen="" style="border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;border-radius: 4px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There is a official plugin https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-aspect-ratio

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // ...
  },
  corePlugins: {
    aspectRatio: false,
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    // ...
  ],
}
```

Or You Can Refer To https://tailwindcss.com/docs/aspect-ratio

Comment: Why is it set to false?

Answer (score 0):

use this class

```html
<iframe class="w-full aspect-video"></iframe>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Treat the iframe as any other element utilizing media queries with tailwind. You can do this applying w-full and h-full with the Tailwind plugins mentioned before as the parent div or you can manually do it as below:

```
<iframe
        class="w-full h-[300px] sm:h-[450px] md:h-[600px] lg:h-[450px] xl:h-[600px]"
        src="">
</iframe>
```